# How to allow svg elements using the new Sanitize api

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html-sanitizer-api

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Sanitizer_API

Using the html sanitizer api, it is removing the 'svg' tag even though I am adding it to the allowed list. How can I allow 'svg' tags?

Currently using chrome 105.

```
const cfg = Sanitizer.getDefaultConfiguration();
cfg.allowCustomElements = true;
cfg.allowElements.push('svg');
cfg.allowElements.push('slot');
cfg.allowElements.push('path');
const sanitizer = new Sanitizer(cfg)
const str = `<button>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M7.41,8.58L12,13.17L16.59,8.58L18,10L12,16L6,10L7.41,8.58Z"></path>
        </svg>
</button>`

const container = document.createElement('div')
container.setHTML(str, {sanitizer: sanitizer})
```

The sanitizer is removing the svg tag and everything inside.
const hasSvg = cfg.allowElements.includes('svg'); // is returning true

Comment: Perhaps something to do with [this](https://wicg.github.io/sanitizer-api/#namespaces), though I can't figure out exactly how

Comment: Latest discussions are at https://github.com/WICG/sanitizer-api/issues/181 Currently it's HTML only...

Answer (score 0):

This is an experimental feature and has very poor support. In addition, it only works with the HTTPS protocol. That is, you cannot work with it through a regular localhost.
You have to wait a little longer for bold use.

Try the [purify-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/purify-html) library instead. It works with the more common browser API, is very lightweight (MINIFIED + GZIPPED - 462 bytes!) and safely removes dangerous tags.

Comment: I only need it to work in the current version of chrome via HTTPS and I cannot use 3rd party libraries.  The trick for me is how to allow SVG.  I think I can wrap my svg tag in another custom element as a work around.  This should work since the sanitization seems to happen at a string parsing level.  If a custom element later adds svg, then this parser should not care.

Comment: Why can't you use third party libraries? If you are cleaning
strings from potentially dangerous HTML - you will need specialized
tool. What is now from the native - has a catastrophically low
support. And writing yourself without special knowledge is risky. In general, I think that in matters of security you need to distrust yourself very much in order to get a good product.

Comment: Alexander, lets say I work in an industry that requires you to be on the most current version of all software and libs used and has an approval process that can take up to 3 years before the software can be deployed to their air-gapped private network. The conflict between the approval timeline and OSS release timeline basically means no 3rd party libs.  On the positive note, you would be surprised how effective using template literals and basic encoding of non-template data can be. Passes all the OWASP and webInspect tests. But I'm always looking for newer ways.